# ORMs that can generate classes from an existing database

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, orm

**Except for Entity Framework, which ORMs can generate classes from an existing database?**

I am looking to move away from Entity Framework because it is just too slow.  I am wondering which ORMs out there are going to be the easiest to migrate a fairly complex WCF service to (from Entity Framework and an Existing Database).

Comment: Too slow how? Code execution? Developer tools? Query speed?

Comment: @NathanAldenSr - It is not the developer tools (those are great) and it is not actual query speed (I have profiled those and added indexes as needed).  My guess is that it is materialization that is getting me, but I have not dug into which part of the EF system is too slow.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will work for you, but I have migrated from EF to dapper with great results. As far as generating code, dapper doesn't do it, but using a tool like codesmith or t4 you can quickly get a lot of your run of the mill classes generated.

If performance is your top concern, youd have a hard time beating dapper.